# FFMpeg - add background music

Tags: video, ffmpeg

here is what i have:
input1.avi - video that contain sounds.
input2.avi - video that doesn't contain sounds.
music.mp3 - audio file.

i want to add background music(music.mp3 file) to the video.

```
C:\input1.avi -i C:\music.mp3 -shortest -c:v copy -c:a copy C:\output1.avi
```

then output1.avi is the same as input1 - movie with sounds but without the background music (music.mp3)

when i try to use the other file (video without sounds):

```
C:\input2.avi -i C:\music.mp3 -shortest -c:v copy -c:a copy C:\output2.avi
```

then output2.avi is the same as input2 + it have the background music.

so why input1 does not contain the background music???
and how can i decrease or increase the volume of music.mp3 file?

thanks.

---

console output:

```
C:\motionbee\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg -i C:\input.avi
-i C:\music.mp3 -shortest -c:v copy -filter_
complex "[0:a]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo[0a];[1]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo,volume=
1.5[1a];[0a][1a]amix[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -ac 2 C:\output1.avi
ffmpeg version N-78949-g6f5048f Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenc
ore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --ena
ble-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable
-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --ena
ble-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx
264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable
-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 27.101 / 57. 27.101
  libavformat    57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 39.100 /  6. 39.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, avi, from 'C:\input.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.28.100
  Duration: 00:02:05.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 450 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 720
x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 440 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 k
b/s
[mp3 @ 00000000005c8020] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 32370.
Input #1, mp3, from 'C:\music.mp3':
  Metadata:
    title           : Broadcast News Package - News Intro
    artist          : After Effects News Template
  Duration: 00:01:57.89, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 194 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.26
File 'C:\output1.avi' already exists. Overwrite
? [y/N] y
Output #0, avi, to 'C:\output1.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf57.28.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR
 3:2], q=2-31, 440 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, stereo
, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.27.101 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (mp3) -> aformat
  Stream #1:0 (mp3) -> aformat
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  amix -> Stream #0:1 (libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 3118 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    6917kB time=00:02:05.76 bitrate= 450.6kbits
/s speed= 867x
video:6754kB audio:74kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
 overhead: 1.307944%
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When multiple streams are available, and no map is specified, ffmpeg picks one video and one audio stream from among the inputs.

Since you will likely need to re-encode audio, you can use

```
ffmpeg -i C:\input1.avi -i C:\music.mp3 -c:v copy \
       -filter_complex "[0:a]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo,apad[0a];[1]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo,volume=1.5[1a];[0a][1a]amerge[a]" \
       -map 0:v -map "[a]" -ac 2 C:\output1.avi
```

Comment: i got an error:
[Parsed_amerge_1 @ 00000000001901a0] No channel layout for input 1
[Parsed_amerge_1 @ 00000000001901a0] No channel layout for input 2
[AVFilterGraph @ 000000000015dfe0] The following filters could not choose their
formats: Parsed_amerge_1
Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output.
Error configuring complex filters.
I/O error

Comment: Please paste the full console output of the command in the question.

Comment: C:\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg -i C:\input.avi
-i C:\music.mp3 -shortest -c:v copy -filter_
complex "[1]volume=1.5[1a];[0][1a]amerge[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -ac 2 C:\output1.avi
ffmpeg version N-78949-g6f5048f Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)

Comment: libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 27.101 / 57. 27.101
  libavformat    57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 39.100 /  6. 39.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, avi, from 'C:\output.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.28.100
  Duration: 00:02:05.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 450 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 720

Comment: Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 720
x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 440 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 k
b/s
[mp3 @ 000000000012bc20] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 32370.
Input #1, mp3, from 'C:\motionbee\sound_tracks\After_Effects_News.mp3':
  Metadata:
    title           : Broadcast News Package - News Intro
    artist          : After Effects News Template
  Duration: 00:01:57.89, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 194 kb/s

Comment: Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.26
[Parsed_amerge_1 @ 00000000001901a0] No channel layout for input 1
[Parsed_amerge_1 @ 00000000001901a0] No channel layout for input 2
[AVFilterGraph @ 000000000015dfe0] The following filters could not choose their
formats: Parsed_amerge_1
Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output.
Error configuring complex filters.
I/O error

Comment: Command edited. And paste the console output in the question, not the comments.

Comment: you right about the misspelling. i changed it bust still have an error. i copy the console output to the question again...

Comment: Looks like your intro sound is very short. So, use amix instead. See edited command.

Comment: well, the mp3 is 1:57 minutes.
the video is 2:05 minutes.
i changed to amex and still video created without sound at all.
i added the output into the question...

Comment: Can you upload the two files - input1 and music?

Comment: Upload it to datafilehost

Comment: please notice that the music start but stop when the scene change.
files links:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tnrcptiuw95sdgt/input.avi?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ap509047tdp7mx/music.mp3?dl=0

Comment: Fixed. See edited command. Your input1.avi is weird. Its resolution changes after the intro, i.e. it's a concat of mismatched clips. So its audio is only 4.8 seconds long. The `-shortest` was stopping the encode at that point. I then added apad to the AVI's audio so the amerge will merge the entire music. Basically, the AVI is not a well-formed file.

Comment: i ran the command . but it ran more the 20 minutes and wasn't close to be finished. in addition the  file was more then 5GB... so i dont think its good solution....

any other idea what to do?

Comment: ok thanks a lot!! its now works! :)
just one more small issue. the music end at 1:55 and the video end at 2:05.  so can we insert -shortest somewhere?

Comment: Add `-t 116` as an output option.

Comment: its helped for the specific video.
 but when i used same script with music length 4:00 minutes and movie length 3 minutes, its cut in 1:55 again. but in this scenario i want the output will stop on 3:00 minutes.... how can i do it? not with -shortest??

Comment: Yeah, you can try shortest.

Comment: if i use shortest
ffmpeg -i C:\upload\input.avi -i C:\upload\music.mp3 -shortest -c:v copy -filter_complex "[0:a]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo,apad[0a];[1]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo,volume=0.5[1a];[0a][1a]amerge[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -ac
 2 C:\upload\output1.avi

then the music stop after the scene change

Comment: Yeah, because your AVI files are weirdly stitched. Use `-t N` instead, where N is value in seconds.

Comment: good job but i want to decrease background sound and increase my sound ... how can i do

Comment: It works, but as the music is shoter thant the original audio, both music and original audio stops when the music stops

Answer (score 4):

I tried this command seems to be working.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[out]" -map 1:v -map "[out]" -c:v copy -shortest output.mp4
```

Things changed :

1. Unknown encoder 'libfdk_aac'
2. This syntax is deprecated. Use '|' to separate the list items `('stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3' instead of 'stereo|c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3')`